# Why wont my webpage adjust automatically to the size of the window

Tags: html, css

Hi there I'm having some trouble with some code for school. I need to get my webpage to adjust as I adjust the internet explorer window, any help is very appreciated and all of my code is posted below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Cycling Tours</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Cstyles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <article id="HeadContent>
        <header id="Head">
            <h1 id="CycleTours">Cycle Tours</h1>
            <figure>
                <img id="BikeAxle" src="images/bicycle_axle.jpg" alt="bikeaxle"/>
                <img id="BikeBanner" src="images/bicycle_banner.jpg" alt="bikebanner"/>
            </figure>
        </header>
    </article>
</body>
</html>
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#Head {
  background-color: #C0C0C0;
  height: 600px;
  width: 80%;
  margin-left: 10.5%;
}
#BikeBanner {
  position: absolute;
  width: 70%;
  margin-top: -4%;
  height: 300px;
  margin-left: 2.2%;
}
#CycleTours {
  position: fixed;
  margin-top: 7%;
  color: white;
  margin-left: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
}
#HeadContent {
  margin-left: 12%;
  margin-right: 12%;
}
```

Comment: Use `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` and of course your css will do the rest.

Comment: @claudios I don't think that's the issue. Watch closely. The OP says IE.

Comment: viewport is for the mobile devices, not the desktop window adjustment

Comment: @PraveenKumar, Yeah the first time I saw the post is it don't have any css attached. My bad

Comment: Please explore http://foundation.zurb.com/

Comment: @claudios No probs. But still, it is not relevant for IE.

Comment: @Grasper Why? Seriously, why?

Comment: @PraveenKumar because he needs to learn how the grid structure works and can benefit him?

Comment: @Grasper Mate, he's doing a school project. Read the question. Won't I have suggested Bootstrap then? Bootstrap FTW! :P

Comment: Maybe you can try `floating divs` with specific width

Comment: Or Flex. right? :)

Comment: @PraveenKumar, why do you think is for the school project? I make sites for schools every day as professional.

Comment: @Grasper First line says, *Hi there I'm having some trouble with some code for school.*

Comment: @claudios I guess this person is just a student, and he's seeking our help. Looks crazy though, because IE doesn't support responsive stuff. And the code looks pretty `absolute` so, I am not in a position to go through. My best suggestion for people here, is not to suggest anything like a framework or some advanced CSS3 stuff like Flexbox.

Comment: ya its just a lab I have to complete and my prof wants me to have everything stay aligned on the right even when the window resizes but I cant seem to figure it out.

Comment: @awill Do you wanna share us a screenshot of how it looks?

Comment: Ya I just posted 2 as a answer.